# Why move_uploaded_file method does not work in WordPress?

Tags: php, wordpress

I created a metabox in wordpress for uploading photo to my plugin custom directory. I used the following code

```
<form  method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="file" name="taggr_upload">
</form>
```

This is the form I created in side the `add_meta_box()` method

Then I add this save_post action hook

```
add_action( 'save_post', 'boj_mbe_save_meta' );

function boj_mbe_save_meta( $post_id ) {
        move_uploaded_file($_FILES['taggr_upload']['tmp_name'], 'photo/'. basename( $_FILES['taggr_upload']['name'] ));
}
```

Why it doesn't save into my photo folder when I open my folder?

This is the full code:

```
<?php 
/*
Plugin Name: random plug
Plugin URI: http://example.com/wordpress-plugins/my-plugin
Description: A plugin demonstrating Cron in WordPress
Version: 1.0
Author: Brad Williams
Author URI: http://wrox.com
License: GPLv2
*/

add_action('init', 'register_tagging_post');

 function register_tagging_post(){
       $tagging_args = array(
           'public' => true,
           'supports' => array(
               'title',
               'thumbnail'

           ), 
           'query_var' => 'tagging',
           'rewrite' => array(
              'slug' => 'tagging',
              'with_front' => false
           ),
            'labels' => array(
            'name' => 'Albums',
            'singular_name' => 'Album',
            'add_new' => 'Add New Album',
            'add_new_item' => 'Add New Album',
            'edit_item' => 'Edit Album',
            'new_item' => 'New Album',
            'view_item' => 'View Album',
            'search_items' => 'Search Albums',
            'not_found' => 'No Albums Found',
            'not_found_in_trash' => 'No Albums Found In Trash'
        ),
       );

       register_post_type('tagging', $tagging_args);
 }


 //add metabox
 add_action( 'add_meta_boxes', 'boj_mbe_create' );

function boj_mbe_create() {
    //create a custom meta box
    add_meta_box( 'boj-meta', 'My Custom Meta Box', 'boj_mbe_function', 'tagging', 'normal', 'high' );
}

function boj_mbe_function( $post ) {
    //retrieve the meta data values if they exist
    ?>
    <form  method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">

     <input type="file" name="taggr_upload">
    </form>

    <?php
         echo WP_PLUGIN_DIR;

//hook to save the meta box data
add_action( 'save_post', 'boj_mbe_save_meta' );

function boj_mbe_save_meta( $post_id ) {
    //verify the meta data is set
    if ( isset( $_POST['taggr_upload'] ) ) {
        //save the meta data

       $path_to_plugin = WP_PLUGIN_DIR . '/yeah';
     move_uploaded_file($_FILES['taggr_upload']['tmp_name'], $path_to_plugin . '/photo/'. basename( $_FILES['taggr_upload']['name'] ));
    }
}

//create custom post column
}
?>
```

Why it doesn't work?

Comment: Have you checked whether `isset($_POST['taggr_upload'])` is actually true?

Comment: sorry actually that code is not needed, i have a long code actually i just simplify it so it specific to the problem

Comment: Why do you have an action hook **and** a function inside the function `boj_mbe_function`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**EDIT**

Okay first of all, you can not **upload** a file from any of the metaboxes. Reason? Well, because WordPress wraps all of the post stuff inside a `<form>` which does not have the necessary attributes to upload files.

So the solution is to provide an option to upload using WordPress default media uploader and save the URL instead.

Here is a working example. Please use this as a guide, not as your production code. In reality you'd like to fine tune the media uploader button so that multiple button can add multiple urls to multiple inputs.

http://example.com/wordpress-plugins/my-plugin
    Description: A plugin demonstrating Cron in WordPress
    Version: 1.0
    Author: Brad Williams
    Author URI: http://wrox.com
    License: GPLv2
    */

```
add_action( 'init', 'register_tagging_post' );

function register_tagging_post() {
    $tagging_args = array(
        'public' => true,
        'supports' => array(
            'title',
            'thumbnail'
        ),
        'query_var' => 'tagging',
        'rewrite' => array(
            'slug' => 'tagging',
            'with_front' => false
        ),
        'labels' => array(
            'name' => 'Albums',
            'singular_name' => 'Album',
            'add_new' => 'Add New Album',
            'add_new_item' => 'Add New Album',
            'edit_item' => 'Edit Album',
            'new_item' => 'New Album',
            'view_item' => 'View Album',
            'search_items' => 'Search Albums',
            'not_found' => 'No Albums Found',
            'not_found_in_trash' => 'No Albums Found In Trash'
        ),
    );
    register_post_type( 'tagging', $tagging_args );
}


//add metabox
add_action( 'add_meta_boxes', 'boj_mbe_create' );

function boj_mbe_create() {
    //create a custom meta box
    add_meta_box( 'boj-meta', 'My Custom Meta Box', 'boj_mbe_function', 'tagging', 'normal', 'high' );
}

function boj_mbe_function( $post ) {
    $file_meta_data = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'taggr_file', true );
?>
<input type="text" class="regular-text" name="taggr_file" id="taggr_file" value="<?php echo $file_meta_data; ?>" />
<button id="taggr_upload" class="button-primary">Upload</button>
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
        // Uploading files
        var file_frame;
        jQuery('#taggr_upload').on('click', function( event ) {

            event.preventDefault();

            // If the media frame already exists, reopen it.
            if ( file_frame ) {
                file_frame.open();
                return;
            }

            // Create the media frame.
            file_frame = wp.media.frames.file_frame = wp.media({
                title: jQuery( this ).data( 'uploader_title' ),
                button: {
                    text: jQuery( this ).data( 'uploader_button_text' ),
                },
                multiple: false  // Set to true to allow multiple files to be selected
            });

            // When an image is selected, run a callback.
            file_frame.on( 'select', function() {
                // We set multiple to false so only get one image from the uploader
                var attachment = file_frame.state().get('selection').first().toJSON();
                // Do something with attachment.id and/or attachment.url here
                $('#taggr_file').val(attachment.url);
            });

            // Finally, open the modal
            file_frame.open();
        });
    });
</script>
    <?php
}

//hook to save the meta box data
add_action( 'save_post', 'boj_mbe_save_meta' );

function boj_mbe_save_meta( $post_id ) {
    //verify the meta data is set
    if ( isset( $_POST['taggr_file'] ) ) {
        update_post_meta( $post_id, 'taggr_file', stripslashes( $_POST['taggr_file'] ) );
    }
}
```

If you're still facing any problem, then feel free to reply :)

Comment: still doesn't work bro, you can use my full code here and try it out

Comment: Nevermind about my last comment. There seems to be too much confusion in your code. I will add a fresh working one in a while.

Comment: thx bro, thumbs up for ur work, it work for me, i'm really sry for late reply because the time difference. I am actually not really familiar with jquery, (javascript and php is fine). Can you make an example using wp_upload_bits or wp_handle_upload function???I guess these are wordpress function for adding attachment also.Appreciated :)

Comment: Yes they are. But I do not think you can upload a file from a metabox of a custom post type. So in theory, you've to make your own plugin page which will complecate the answer.